# ST_Contour doesn't produce polygon

Tags: postgis, contour

With this version:

`PostgreSQL 14.0, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit`

`POSTGIS="3.3.2 3.3.2" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="140" GEOS="3.11.1-CAPI-1.17.1" PROJ="7.2.1" GDAL="GDAL 3.4.3, released 2022/04/22" LIBXML="2.9.9" LIBJSON="0.12" LIBPROTOBUF="1.2.1" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)" RASTER`

I have a point table with some other numeric columns and about 1000 rows. I need to create contour lines and contour polygons from it.

So, first I create a raster table from the table, and then I am going to produce the contours from this raster table. Producing contour lines works, but not contour polygons.

This works:
`ST_Contour(...,polygonize=>false);`

This not, and the same result as setting polygonize with false:
`ST_Contour(...,polygonize=>true);`

---

The ST_Contour definition :
`setof record ST_Contour(raster rast, integer bandnumber=1, double precision level_interval=100.0, double precision level_base=0.0, double precision[] fixed_levels=ARRAY[], boolean polygonize=false);`

For parameter `polygonize`:
**If true, contour polygons will be created**, rather than polygon lines.

In this page : [RT_ST_Contour](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Contour.html)

---

Has anyone encountered this situation ever?